# Orientation on finite dimensional vector spaces over finite fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, vector-spaces, differential-topology, finite-fields

For finite-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector spaces, we define an orientation to be an equivalence class of ordered bases, where $B_1 \sim B_2$ iff the change of basis matrix $A$ taking $B_{1}$ to $B_{2}$ has positive determinant. Then there are two equivalence classes, one which we call, "positive" and the other we call, "negative".

I wanted to know if any work has been done to extend this to finite-dimensional vector spaces over finite fields. My idea was to do everything as above, but replace the condition $\det A>0$ with $\det A$ is a quadratic residue. This should split the bases into two equivalence classes just as above.

I played around with these and noticed some interesting things. For example let $q=p^{f}$ and $\mathbb F_{q}$ be an $\mathbb F_{p}$ vector space. Unlike the case for $\mathbb R$, if $q \not\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then switching any two vectors in your basis doesn't change the equivalence class, because the determinant of the corresponding change of basis matrix is $-1$, which is a quadratic residue in this case.

Has any work been done on this, or are there any other definitions or related concepts that might be of interest?

Comment: Nice question. Here is a random thought that might inspire someone: The fact that there are two orientations of an $\mathbf{R}$-vector space comes from the fact that $\operatorname{GL}_n\mathbb{R}$ has exactly two connected components.

Connected doesn't make sense if your field is finite, but maybe there is something about $\operatorname{GL}_n\mathbb{F}_q$ which might be related to "orientations".

Comment: You don't need to write $B_1$~$B_2$.  You can write $B_1\sim B_2$, entirely within $\TeX$, so that it follows standard conventions of size and spacing and harmony between fonts, etc.  (I changed it above.)

Comment: Might even and odd permutations have something to do with it?

Comment: What happens in vector spaces over $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: You can replace "positive" with "square."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan- Are you saying that because we already know $A$ has nonzero determinant?

Comment: @MichaelHardy- I'm not sure what a proper analogue of positive would be in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: If you think of it as "square" rather than "positive," every determinant is a square in $\Bbb{C}$, so would there only be one analogous equivalence class?

Comment: @Stahl- Right, that's what I'm trying to avoid. I really want to have two equivalence classes so it feels like "positive" and "negative" in some sense. However, maybe that isn't the right thing to do, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Putting a "positive"/"negative" distinction on ${\bf GL}_1(\bf C)\cong C^\times$ or ${\bf GL}_1({\bf F}_q)\cong{\bf F}_q^\times$ alone seems a bit removed from the original idea behind sign and orientation (which is intrinsically tied to the topological notion of connected components in the symmetries of ordered bases), although using quadratic residues is an interesting algebraic alternative.

Comment: @Dylan: ah, I see you already noticed that you can replace "positive" with "square."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept which generalizes to all fields is not an orientation but a "volume form," by which I mean a nonzero element of the top exterior power $\Lambda^n(V)$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $k$. When $k = \mathbb{R}$, the space of volume forms has two connected components (indeed it can be noncanonically identified with $k^{\times} = \mathbb{R}^{\times}$), and a choice of such a connected component gives an orientation. More generally, if $G$ is any topological group, looking at connected components gives a natural homomorphism $G \to \pi_0(G)$, so one can think about a choice of orientation as a choice of element in the image of the natural map
$$\Lambda^n(V)^{\times} \to \pi_0 \left( \Lambda^n(V)^{\times} \right)$$

Over an arbitrary field you can just pick any quotient group of $\Lambda^n(V)^{\times}$ and consider the corresponding choice of "generalized orientation," e.g. above I suggested quotienting by the subgroup of squares. A choice of volume form will then always naturally give rise to a "generalized orientation."

But it's unclear whether this is of any use.